# How to calculate the checksum of this data?

Tags: flutter, dart, checksum, crc16

I have the following data frame:

```
AA3200010013000CAAAA000000000000000000043000010156EF79
```

"EF 79" is supposed to be the checksum. but I am not very sure how to get this value.

in the documentation it says:

```
Checksum: data CRC16 checksum except for frame head. The calibration algorithm adopts CCITT-16, calibration polynomials is X16 + X15 + X2 + 1, initiation value is set as 0.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you drop the leading `aa`, then this CRC-16 of the remainder:

```
width=16  poly=0x8005  init=0x0000  refin=false  refout=false  xorout=0x0000  check=0xfee8  residue=0x0000  name="CRC-16/UMTS"
```

gives `ef79`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, sorry I am a bit new to this CRC and data packet validation. could you show me the steps pls?

Comment: The steps using what? You have provided no information on what language, platform, how you get the data, anything about the environment in which you need to do this calculation.

Comment: I am using dart and flutter to parse this data from a BLE device.

Comment: I was able to find the calculated checksum via this website: https://crccalc.com
However, the result comes under the CRC-16/BUYPASS algorithm. Whereas the documentation says `The calibration algorithm adopts CCITT-16`

Comment: Yes, it also goes by the name CRC-16/BUYPASS. See [this catalog](https://reveng.sourceforge.io/crc-catalogue/16.htm). It is _not_ CRC-16/CCITT, which is reflected, where this CRC is not. Regardless, the name does not matter. I have provided you with the complete description of the CRC parameters, which is all you need. You can search here on stackoverflow or elsewhere with google for CRC implementations in Dart.

Comment: Thanks, Mark, you have pointed me in the right direction. I am trying to find a dart/Flutter package to perform the calculation. looking into this ATM: https://pub.dev/packages/crclib

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I implemented the checksum calculation:

```
int crc16umts(List<int> bytes) {
  int crc = 0x0000;
  const int polynomial = 0x8005;
  for (final byte in bytes) {
    crc ^= byte << 8;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      if ((crc & 0x8000) != 0) {
        crc = (crc << 1) ^ polynomial;
      } else {
        crc <<= 1;
      }
    }
  }
  return crc & 0xFFFF;
}

void main() {
  final data = '3200010013000CAAAA000000000000000000043000010156';
  final bytes = List<int>.generate(
      data.length ~/ 2, (i) => int.parse(data.substring(i * 2, i * 2 + 2), radix: 16));
  final checksum = crc16umts(bytes);
  print(checksum.toRadixString(16).toUpperCase()); // EF79
}
```